# Hide some spans but not all with CSS only

Tags: html, css

I have the following html

```
<span id="ctl00">
<span><a class="ms-sitemapdirectional" href="/lnd">Team Site</a></span>
<span> &gt; </span>
<span><a class="ms-sitemapdirectional" href="url.aspx">lnd test</a></span>
<span> &gt; </span>
<span class="ms-sitemapdirectional">Portal</span>
</span>
```

I can't edit and I need to hide the links and the > (`&gt;`) and only keep the last span (Portal). How can I achieve this with CSS only?

I tried something like:

```
#ctl00>span {visibility:hidden;}
span.ms-sitemapdirectional {visibility: visible}
a.ms-sitemapdirectional {display: none}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: can't be done with CSS alone, unless it's CSS3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#ctl00 span { display: none; }
#ctl00 span.ms-sitemapdirectional { display: inline; }
```

Comment: Hiding the parent span will hide all children.

Comment: In his sample markup, that solves the problem.  The only one he wants to show is span.ms-sitemapdirectional.

Comment: It says "and only keep the last span". Your sample shows all of the internal spans with the class ms-sitemapdirectional. So, the pseudo class :last-child would be required.

Comment: @Chris: Nope, the others are all `a.ms-sitemapdirectional`. The last `.ms-sitemapdirectional` is applied to `<span>`. So Jacob's code works.

Comment: There's only one span with that class.  Look again.

Comment: yes... i just caught that.  However, I just tried the sample code and it doesn't work because of "diplay:none".  When I changed it to "visibility: hidden" it worked but it left space in front of the last span.

Comment: @Chris, should be `display: none`.

Comment: Just got it working, I must have had a typo somewhere.  When I recopied the source, it just worked.  Cool!